# Sparql operation between datetime in select

Tags: datetime, sparql, rdf, owl

I have to write a query that return an intensity value and the associated duration. Duration is calculated with the difference between two datetime values that are stored in the rdf ontology:

- startDate
- stopDate

I write:

```
SELECT ?intensityVal ?startVal ?stopVal ?duration ( (?stopVal - ?startVal) as ?duration)
     WHERE { 
              ?event rrel:existDuringInterval ?interval .              

              ?interval time:hasBeginning ?start . 
              ?start time:inXSDDateTime ?startVal .

              ?interval time:hasEnd ?stop . 
              ?stop time:inXSDDateTime ?stopVal .

              ?event rrel:hasIntensity ?intensity . 
              ?intensity rrel:hasMIValue ?intensityVal .

}
```

After this result I have to count and group by ?duration.

The problem is that ?duration results is blank and I think that I am doing wrong the ?duration calculation.

See:
[image]

Comment: Check the documentation for the SPARQL engine you are using. The difference of two xsd:dateTimes is an xsd;duration.  This calculation is not required by the standatd and not supported in all engines.

Comment: And to extend what @AndyS said, if it's not supported, then the operation would result in an error, which would give you the blank result (i.e., there's no special error value). You could get the duration or else a default value with something like `(coalesce(?date2 - ?date1, "date math not supported") as ?duration)`.

Comment: If `coalesce` is supported.

Comment: @AKSW [**coalesce**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce) is part of the standard.  It *should* be supported (whereas date arithmetic isn't part of the standard).